# Symfony 4: multiple image upload with preview and append/remove functionality

Tags: javascript, forms, symfony, symfony4

**Intro**

I am working on a Symfony 4 application which allows its users to create and edit posts associated with single or multiple images. Data is stored to a database via Doctrine. Each Post has associated PostImage entities which contain filenames of actual image files.

Post entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Post
{
    ...

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="PostImage", mappedBy="post", cascade={"persist", "remove"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    private $images;

   ...
```

PostImage entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class PostImage
{

    ...
    /**
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Post")
    */
    private $post;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=512)
     */
    private $filename;

    ...
```

**What I am trying to do**

Good description of basic file upload to db is [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/upload_file.html). However I would like to make image upload and preview more dynamic.

User should be able to:

- Upload single/multiple images and preview them
- Upload more images
- Remove some images
- Unable to submit a form if all
  images are removed
- Edit post (i.e. perform the above steps) at a
  later time using the same form

**Where I struggle**

JavaScript/DOM manipulation side of the above is quite clear to me. Where I struggle is how to build form or modify types on Symfony side of things.  "$images" field of Post entity is a collection and Symfony way of using forms with collections is described [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html). But I am struggling to understand how to modify this logic to work with files.

If I use unmapped FileType control and upload files on change via AJAX, how do I store and submit links which represent current list of images (some may be new, some - old, some - removed)? Use CollectionType control with HiddenType children which contain references to files uploaded on server?

```
class PostType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('images', CollectionType::class, array(
                'allow_add' => true,
                'allow_remove' => true,
                'by_reference' => false,
                'entry_type' => HiddenType::class
                ))
            ->add('add_images', FileType::class, array(
                'label' => 'Add images',
                'mapped' => false,
                'multiple' => true
                ))
            ->add( //other fields..
            ...
     }
}
```

Comment: Your message helped me solve a similar problem. Thank you!